# Change Array into Database Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array as follows:

```
 Array ( [item-name] => SM58 
         [make] => Shure 
         [model] => SM58 
         [qty] => 5 
         [status] => Available 
       )
```

And I want to change it into a database query such as:

```
INSERT INTO `Inventory`(`item-name`, `make`, `model`, `qty`, `status`) VALUES ('SM58','Shure','SM58','5',[Available])
```

I just can't quite work out how I achieve it.

Comment: To make it easier, you can also do ``INSERT INTO `Inventory` SET `item-name`='SM58', ...``.

Comment: you listed 7 fields and 5 value !!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use PDO:

```
$stmt = $PDOinstance->prepare("
  INSERT INTO `Inventory` (`item-name`, `make`, `model`, `qty`, `status`) 
  VALUES (:item-name, :make, :model, :qty, :status)
");
$stmt->execute($yourArray);
```

Comment: Can you explain the parts of this to me so I can understand it for the future?

PDO means...?

`->execute` sends it to the database?

Comment: @user3207974, PDO stands for [PHP Data Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Basically, this is a safe and pretty easy way to access your database. Please see the documentation for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   foreach($array as $index => $value){
    $fields .= "`".$index."`".",";
    $values .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'".","; //This escapes for mysql
    }
    $fields = rtrim($fields,",");
    $values = rtrim($values,',');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Inventory`($fields) VALUES ($values)";
```

However as the mysql_* function is depreciated you would be better using the above post with PDO and prepared statements or you could use the mysqli_* function along with prepared Statements. Below are the links to the two resources.

PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php  MySQLI: https://www.php.net/mysqli

Comment: Please, **do not** post answers without SQL escaping. This creates enormous liabilities in any applications that use this code.

Comment: @tadman the answer wasn't asking about escaping they was asking about a solution. This is entirely there choice to escape the string before they create an array. Also I am unable to specify an escape unless we know whether they are using PDO, MySQL or mysqli functions which they do not specify

Comment: The solution always involves escaping. When in doubt, give an example in PDO if you're trying to promote the use of that. Look at t1gor's example here which does it correctly. Yours, unfortunately, perpetuates the worst habits of PHP developers.

Comment: @tadman i have noted how to escape for mysql_* function but as it is depreciated i have noted that PDO with prepared statements would be better to use.